# Why pointer in typedef?

Tags: c

Seeing this struct

```
typedef struct Node{
    void *data;
    int pos;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
}*lptr;
```

I wonder why the typedef of `Node` is `*lptr` and not `lptr`.
What difference does the pointer make?

Comment: IMHO, hiding pointers with typedefs is not a good practice. You can't look at a declaration and determine if it is a pointer or a struct; you always have to go back to the typedef. If you never hide pointers in typedefs you don't have this problem. Anyone agree?

Comment: Most programmers do agree that hiding pointers inside typedefs is bad and dangerous practice. However, the question was about why there was a pointer in the typedef and not about whether or not it is good practice. This is a perfectly valid question, no reason to downvote it.

Comment: @Lundin, I didn't down vote it, just expressed my opinion as a comment. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Although it is common to have two `typedef`s - one for the `struct` to avoid the tag, and one for the `struct` pointer to avoid the asterisk, like this

```
typedef struct Node{
    void *data;
    int pos;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
typedef Node* lptr;
```

if the authors want to avoid writing an asterisk after `lptr` or `Node`, they could certainly `typedef` a pointer to `struct Node`.

Answer (score 1):

The typedef is for a pointer type.

`lptr` is the type `struct Node*`

Answer (score 1):

Because the definition (the typedef) is to a pointer type. Removing it makes lptr of type Node, * makes it a *pointer* to a Node.